# SQL Server 2008 parent child table using cte with additional data

Tags: sql-server-2008, parent-child, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have two tables as follows

```
Group
Id,   Name,        ParentId
1,    North,       NULL
2,    South,       NULL
3,    London,      2
4,    Brighton,    2
5,    Fulham,      3
6,    SuperStores, NULL

StoreAndGroup
Id,   StoreId,     GroupId
1,    41,          2
2,    52,          3
3,    88,          5
4,    88,          6
5,    41,          6
```

etc

I want to produce a table that shows all stores that belong to each group (including subgroups), so the above would become

```
GroupId, StoreId
2,       41
2,       52
2,       88
3,       52
3,       88
5,       88
6,       88
6,       41
```

I can use a recursive cte to show me all children of a particular group but am a bit stuck as to how to incorporate the additional data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it turned out to be a simple join

```
WITH
   cteGroups (Id, GroupName, ParentGroupId, GroupLevel)
   AS
   (
     SELECT Id, GroupName, ParentGroupId
     FROM Dim_Group
     UNION ALL
     SELECT g.Id, g.GroupName, g.ParentGroupId
     FROM Dim_Group g
      INNER JOIN cteGroups cg
        ON g.ParentGroupId = cg.Id
  )

  select * from cteGroups inner join dim_groupmember on cteGroups.Id = dim_groupmember.groupid
```

Darren

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this:

```
SELECT GroupId, StoreId
FROM StoresAndGroup
UNION ALL
SELECT ParentId AS GroupId, StoreId
FROM StoresAndGroup s INNER JOIN [Group] g ON g.GroupId = s.GroupId
WHERE g.ParentId IS NOT NULL
```